# Magick R: Remove non-image output (image_read_pdf) from display

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the `image_read_pdf` function from the [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) R package to display images in a shiny app.

````
```{r include = FALSE}
...
qc1 <- image_read_pdf(paste0(figures_dir,'qc_1.pdf'))
```
````

Then I simply print the image...

````
#### Initial QC:
```{r echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message = FALSE, out.height='50%', out.width='80%'}
print(qc1)
```
````

The image displays sans issue but I am getting information about the file before the image is displayed and I would like to remove that output so that it looks nicer.

[image]

I have tried `echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message = FALSE` without success; how can this output be removed?

```
## # A tibble: 2 × 7
##   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
##   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
## 1 PNG     3300   2550 sRGB       TRUE         0 300x300
## 2 PNG     3300   2550 sRGB       TRUE         0 300x300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the developers...

````
#### Initial QC:
```{r echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message = FALSE, out.height='50%', out.width='80%'}
print(qc1, info=F)
```
````